# Overload parent from other child class

Tags: php, oop, overloading

I am not sure if i get the point of OOP but this is my idea:

```
<?php

class Car {
    public $color;

    public function setColor($value) {
        $this->color = $tvalue;
    }
}

class FactoryAudi extends Car {
    public makeTheCar() {   
        //...
    }

    public getParent() {    
        return $this->parent;
    }
}

class Audi extends Car {

    public function setParent($parent) {    
        $this->parent = $parent;
    }
}

$newAudi = FactoryAudi();
$newAudi->makeCar();

$audi = new Audi();
$audi->setParent($newAudi->getParent());
```

I want to overload the parent of a new subclass with the parent ob a different subclass (same parent class). My idea is to preserved the data i have already worked on, but move it to an other class so i can use this data. I my head it just makes sense, but PHP will not let me do is this way.
Is it possible to overload the parent with the same type of parent from an other class?

Comment: Why overload? Just take the instance you already have and inject it into the next class. No inheritance required

Answer (score 0):

FactoryAudi should not extend car.  Inheritance, while a means of Aggregation, is used for the ISA relationship.  Thus, an "Audi" ISA "car", but an automobile factory fails the ISA test for being a car.

Also, since inheritance does 'aggregate' you don't need the 'parent' relationships either.

Comment: The problem is, the `FactoryAudi` being in the Factory is a yet a car, but not ready, but when its ready, i want to transform it into a "real" car. I want to take the "parent" which has all the properties of the car already set and inject it into the new Audi class